# Нужно float, а выводит int

Tags: c, float, int

Сразу извиняюсь за такой большой код, но когда я его немного меняю всё начинает работать.
Вся проблема в самой функции *sum()*, мне нужно что бы из неё выходило число не округленое, а такое как оно есть. Сейчас вывод функции sum() такой:
*Result: 1.000000
Result: 13.000000
Result: 13.000000*

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
float sum(int );

int main() {
    float y;
    double resultat;
    printf("Enter y:\n>> ");
    scanf_s("%f", &y);
    resultat = (1.7*sum(1/4)+2*sum(y+1))/(6-sum(y*y-1));
    printf("Resultat is: %f", resultat);
    return 0;
}

float sum(int x)
{
    int facto = 1;
    double res = 1, stepen;
    for (int i=1;i<=3;i++)
    {
        facto=facto*i;
        stepen = pow(x, i);
        res = stepen/facto + res;

    }
    printf("Result: %f\n", res);
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

у вас функция от целочисленного параметра

```
float sum(int x)
```

а при использовании вы его просто в ноль обращаете

```
1.7*sum(1/4)
```

и еще - `sum(1/4)` всегда означает `sum(0)` - вы же целые делите на целые, используйте лучше что-то из этого:

```
sum(1.0/4)
sum(1/4.0)
sum(1.0/4.0)
sum(0.25)
```

Пример:

```
Enter y:
>> 1.25
Result: 1.283854
Result: 7.679688
Result: 1.750366
Resultat is: 4.127868
```

Comment: а какую поставить double?

Comment: @Pawka, ну раз у вас все в `float`, так и используйте `float` дальше, двойная точность вам вроде не очень нужна. В общем или `float` или `double` по всему коду такой программы, но `float` за глаза должно хватить и работает побыстрее вроде как

Comment: Поставил float так же 13.0000... 1.0000

Comment: @Pawka, а на вход какое значение подаете?

Comment: Подаю для y = 2

Comment: @Pawka, почитайте мой ответ - я еще одну ошибку у вас описал, исправьте ее - и еще - проверяйте работу на вещественных числах, например `1,237437`, а при `x = 2` одна из сумм - `sum(3)` у вас и должна быть целой :)